# Show that $\lvert x-x_1\rvert=c\cdot\lvert x-x_2\rvert$ describes an $n-1$ sphere for $0<c<1$ and a hyperplane for $c=1$

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry

My attempt:

For $c=1$, it is easy to visualize a *2D* plane lying between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and simplifying the equation$\lvert x-x_1\rvert=\lvert x-x_2\rvert$ gives $$x\cdot(x_1-x_2)=\dfrac{(\lvert x_1\rvert^2-\lvert x_2\rvert ^2)}{2}$$

Which is an equation of a hyperplane similar to $z\cdot x=c$ where $z=x_1-x_2$

How do I visualize the $n-1$ sphere when $0 \lt c\lt1$ and proceed with it?

Comment: Two little remarks. 1) You get an $n-1$-hypersphere for _any_ $c >0$ such that $c \neq 1$. 2) The 2D case is the classical Apollonius circle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square everything:$$\|x\|^2  -2 x_1 \cdot x +\|x_1\|^2 = c^2(\|x\|^2-2x_2\cdot x+\|x_2\|^2),$$hence
$$\|x\|^2 -2 \frac{(x_1-c^2x_2)}{1-c^2}\cdot x+\frac{\|x_1\|^2-c^2\|x_2\|^2}{1-c^2},$$
which leads to
$$\left\|x-\frac{(x_1-c^2x_2)}{1-c^2}\right\|^2 =\left\|\frac{(x_1-c^2x_2)}{1-c^2}\right\|^2-\frac{\|x_1\|^2-c^2\|x_2\|^2}{1-c^2}.$$

Now you need to show that the expression on the right hand side is positive, which should be quite easy to do.

Comment: Gotcha. Do you know any way to plot a figure for this equation. Let's say $|x-1|=0.5|x-2|$

Comment: @probabilitydoesntsuck Computer algebra systems like Mathematica can build such plots. And you can always use the formulas in my answer to determine the center and the radius of your circle.

Comment: It should be stressed that the clean solution given by @TZakrevskiy has probably been guided 1) by the knowledge of the 2D case (Apollonius' circles) 2) by the fact that the center $y$ of the sphere, by reason of symmetry, is naturally colinear with $x_1$ and $x_2$, and, as such, can be considered as a weighted average $y = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2$.

Comment: Can you clarify the "which leads to" part?  It's not really clear to me

Comment: @Niebla We are trying to group all terms containing $x$ into one norm (same idea as in solving a quadratic equation). $x\cdot x + 2 a \cdot x + b^2 = (x-a)\cdot (x-a) +b^2-a\cdot a$.